# How to combine OFFSET and PARTITIONBY within many groups have different records by using DAX Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, offset, partition

I face to this problem when I want to lag 1 rank each row for each group, but when I try to use offet I don't know how to implement this. You can see the detail in the picture my solution.

Please help me because I'm not familiar with DAX
[image]

Comment: Please post sample data as text along with expected results.